# Model without View: do I need a Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

I would like to have a Referral model, where user A can refer an Event X to user B. The way I plan to implement it is without Referral Views. I just have a Refer button on a events/show page for create action, and have referred users in users/show page for show. I don't see the need to create a view for referral.

From design pattern point of view, is it OK to create "refer" action in Events_Controller to invoke create method in Referral model, instead of sending it to a designated controller (i.e., Refferals_Controller), which will make call to Referral model?

More generally, should I create controller to allow other controllers to interact with my model, even if I don't need any views for this particular model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a controller to just forward calls to model from other controllers. You can have several models per controller. Or several controllers per model.

Sometimes (if you know what you're doing) you can even call model methods from the view directly ("some rules can be bent, some can be broken" (c) Morpheus ).

Answer (score 4):

Controller is where the http requests come (after passing through Routing).  No incoming requests == no controller. Good when controller complies with REST scheme (index, show, create ...). But you can add non-REST actions as well (Rails Routing supports this: [3 Non-Resourceful Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes))
All interaction with model should probably go in the model class.(Edit: I mean code)